# Rewrite recursion function without using recursion

Tags: python, function, loops, recursion, url-rewriting

I'm currently working on a function which is pretty easy with recursion. But I have the problem that I'm always getting an error because the function gets called to often. So I have to rewrite this function so that no recursion is used.
This is the function with recursion:

```
def calculate_stock(stock, stock_base_line, days):
    sales_after_stock = stock - (stock_base_line/14)
    if sales_after_stock > 0:
        days +=1
        return calculate_stock(sales_after_stock, stock_base_line, days)        
    else:
        return days
```

The loop should stop when `sales_after_stock`  is lower than `0`.

Now I tried to rewrite the recursion:

```
def calculate_stock(stock, stock_base_line, days):
    sales_after_stock = stock - (stock_base_line/14)     
    while(sales_after_stock > 0):
        if sales_after_stock > 0:
            days +=1
            sales_after_stock = sales_after_stock - (stock_base_line/14)                   
        else:
            return days
    else:
        return days
```

So it does not properly subtract the value of `sales_after_stock` and thus the loop is infinite. How can I solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't the variable be called `stock_after_sales` rather than `sales_after_stock`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with you implementation:

- You do not need to check `if sales_after_stock > 0` within the while loop, as this is checked before each iteration of the loop.
- You are not subtracting anything from `sales_after_stock` - each time you always set it equal to `stock - stock_base_line / 14`

This should work for you:

```
def calculate_stock(stock, stock_base_line, days):

    sales_after_stock = stock - stock_base_line / 14
    while sales_after_stock > 0:
        days += 1
        sales_after_stock -= stock_base_line / 14

    return days
```

Comment: I implemented your solution. I get your point but it's still an infinite loop.

Comment: That's only possible if your stock_base_line is negative or 0

Comment: I guess you don't have to have `days` as a function argument now? It could be an internal variable, initialized to zero